# Who is the creator of Chinese language?

Tags: history

Who is the creator of Chinese language? When I googled "Who is the creator of Chinese language?" it didn't show what I expected. I will be very grateful for any answers.

Comment: Myths said 倉頡 created writing, but it is just a myth. No one knows who created the first written word

Comment: Hi @TangHo, so there is no answer to this question?

Comment: In order for any written record to be made, a written language has to be invented first, without which no written record could be made in the first place. And since the period of time from the invention of the first written proper word to sufficient maturity for a written record to be actually made at all is immense, it therefore follows that there would never be any written record of the inventor or more likely a series of inventors over a vast expand of time. If we depend on oral tradition, this too needs to be written down and the vast expand of time needed garbled up the story anyway.

Comment: @MyCar There is no clear answer. But some studies suggest the Cishan People 磁山文化人群. See my answer below.

Comment: @MyCar the only languages that are created by someone are artificial/conlangs.  So just like it is hard to say if the chicken or the egg came first, we can study history to get some good ideas of important chinese language points in history.  Even in modern times it is impossible to say exactly when a language changes let alone looking at a language thousands of years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No individual created it; it was created by the Chinese people over thousands of years.

[Oracle bone scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) (甲骨文) date back to the Shang Dynasty, somewhere in the ballpark of 3200 years ago.  Prior to this, we don't have a written record.  Records of the [Xia Dynasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xia_dynasty) (the dynasty prior to the Shang Dynasty) come from oral tradition subsequently recorded during the Shang Dynasty (other than fossils, artifacts, etc.):

> There are no contemporaneous records of the Xia, who are not mentioned in the oldest Chinese texts, since the earliest oracle bone inscriptions date from the late Shang period (13th century BC).

The Xia Dynasty is where Chinese history blurs into mythology.

Through the fossil record (e.g. [Peking Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peking_Man)), we know that Chinese ancestors have been in China for [tens of thousands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recent_African_origin_of_modern_humans), if not hundreds of thousands of years.  So who knows how far back the Chinese language goes.

Comment: Peking Man was unrelated to any modern human population.